# How to calculate the distance between two points using Euclidean distance?

Tags: python, list, euclidean-distance, cartesian-coordinates

**Answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62244753/13651848).**

I have the following points in a cartesian plane

```
points = [(4, 5), (-0, 2), (4, 7), (1, -3), (3, -2), (4, 5), (3, 2), (5, 7), (-5, 7), (2, 2), (-4, 5), (0, -2), (-4, 7), (-1, 3), (-3, 2), (-4, -5), (-3, 2), (5, 7), (5, 7), (2, 2), (9, 9), (-8, -9)]
```

And I need to find the closest point to the center using the Euclidean distance.

So far a I have done this:

```
import math
euclidean_distance=[]
distance = math.sqrt(sum([((x+y)**2) for (x,y) in points]))

for (x,y) in points:
    int(distance)
    euclidean_distance.append(distance)

min_distance=min(euclidean_distance)

print(distance)
print(euclidean_distance)
print(min_distance)
```

and the results are:

```
38.71692136521188
[38.71692136521188, 38.71692136521188, 38.71692136521188, 38.71692136521188, 38.71692136521188, 38.71692136521188, 38.71692136521188, 38.71692136521188, 38.71692136521188, 38.71692136521188, 38.71692136521188, 38.71692136521188, 38.71692136521188, 38.71692136521188, 38.71692136521188, 38.71692136521188, 38.71692136521188, 38.71692136521188, 38.71692136521188, 38.71692136521188, 38.71692136521188, 38.71692136521188]
38.71692136521188
```

Why is not calculating the Euclidean distance in each point of the list?

Comment: `euclidean_distance.append(distance)`: you're adding *n* times the same value `distance` in the list, and this value `distance` is not changed during the loop. You probably want to define `distance` as a function and not a single value.

Comment: It's `sqrt(x**2 + y**2)`, not `(x+y)**2`.

Comment: If you're running python >= 3.8, math module has a `dist` function you can make use of. here's the [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html)

Answer (score 1):

Finally I did this and worked for me:

```
import math

distance_points=[]

def euclidean_distance (points):
    return math.sqrt((x**2+y**2))

for (x,y) in (points): 
    distance=euclidean_distance(points)
    distance_points.append(distance)


print(distance_points)
```

Comment: That will blow - did you mean `euclidean_distance(x, y)` then `distance=euclidean_distance(x, y)` ?